# How do I filter my data with LinqPad using Linq

Tags: sql-server, linq, linqpad

```
DateTime data = new DateTime();
var result = from customer in TableNames
orderby customer.BirthDate descending
select customer;
var badData = result.Where(it => DateTime.TryParse(it.BirthDate, out data) == false).ToList();
```

I am trying to find out all the data in the TableName which contain bad data.
The BirthDate column is a VARCHAR(255) and therefore a string.

I am trying to use LinqPad 6 to get the data from the table then TryParse to see which rows this will fail on. I expect my badData should contain a List of rows which contain bad data.

However LinqPad doesn't like the last line. It's trying to convert my C# statements to SQL

Comment: `DateTime.TryParse` is not convertible to SQL. Use `AsEnumerable()` before `Where`, if there is not too much records.

Comment: If the number of records is too many, then you can use ExecuteQuery with a tsql query , eg `var badData = this.ExecuteQuery<TableNames>("Select * from TableNames where TRY_PARSE(BirthDate AS datetime2 USING 'en-US') is null").ToList();`